# mysql - How expensive is increment a column by 1 and re-index it

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, sql-update

Lets say I have a big mysql table "articles", and a column "views" with an index. whenever i want to increment the views by 1, what of the following mysql does?

1. Re indexing the the row O(logn)
2. Using the index current location, and move it just if it needs to be move O(1) in most cases.
3. A third secret option.

Comment: MySQL use B-tree indexes. There's no need to reindex the entire table, moving it is the obvious design and it would be incredibly surprising if it did anything else.

Comment: [This answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/139792/123809) in [dba.se] says that it deletes the old index and inserts the new index.

Comment: B-Trees are balanced indexes.  Changing a single value could throw everything off and require regenerating the entire index.  In most cases, though, the answer is (1) -- finding the new position which should be close and adjusting local values.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Properly designed, rebalancing does not require regenerating the entire index.  I added more details to [_this answer_](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/139792/1876) .